# Email Confirmation: UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync Error : Name cannot be null or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, email-confirmation

I am trying to write code for email confirmation during email registration for my website. I have a bit customized User model which is similar to regular User code.

The code for sending the email confirmation is in within the `Register` action:

```
userService.InsertUser(user);

var appuser = new ApplicationUser(user); //{ UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
appuser.UserName = model.Email;
//var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(appuser, model.Password);
//if (result.Succeeded)
//{
//    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

//    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
//    // Send an email with this link
string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(appuser.Id);
//string htmlcode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = appuser.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(appuser.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

return RedirectToAction("RegisterComplete");
```

From the code, I got the `callbackurl` which is like `http://localhost:63599/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=22&code=C3mfUtYqGzVCsrCnE5VDzC0wfsbgP6lMSVgqFk25kym3uGh0%2B%2Bltqyh0VRim1ulbwSRHBzAgUCJ1WceipbRcErddmNJqzkksZN50QO%2FqTRprpgKcW19wX33QtftwCh7zUz%2B01aghCdg8jZ8Ff%2FNVfRvbjyIW0wavN0Ueq3xl6jBmrv%2BrnbtuKLJO%2BuFE2zHF`

When I type the code into the browser, it will run the `ConfirmEmail` action from AccountController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        //if (result.Succeeded)
        //{
        //    UserService userService = new UserService();
        //    long uid = long.Parse(userId);
        //    User user = userService.GetBy(u => u.UserID == uid).FirstOrDefault();
        //    user.IsVerified = true;
        //    userService.Update(user);
        //}
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
    }
```

But the `result.Succeeded` is `false`. And `result.Error[0] : Name cannot be null or empty`.
I cannot find anymore information about this error in this context and therefore I am quite stuck.

If I change the confirmation code, I will get `result.Error[0]: Invalid token`, this made me think that at least my token has been correct. But I don't what this error is complaining about.

Any help/pointers will be appreciated.